# Tailwind Custom Colours not Working in Angular Production Build

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I've got a set of colours in Tailwind, all of which work when using `ng serve` or the development build of Angular.

However, some colours don't seem to work when using the production build of the site. I've tried placing the colours in `theme.extend.colors` which does not seem to work.

Here's an example of some of my colours:

```
module.exports = {
purge: ['./src/**/*.html', './src/**/*.ts'],
darkMode: false,
theme: {
    colors: {
        red: colors.red,
        blue: colors.blue,
        neutral: colors.grey,
        success: {
            ['50']: colors.green['100'],
            ['100']: colors.green['110'],
            ['200']: colors.green['120'],
            ['300']: colors.green['130'],
            ['400']: colors.green['140'],
            ['500']: colors.green['150'],
            ['600']: colors.green['160'],
        },
        warning: {
            ['50']: colors.orange['100'],
            ['100']: colors.orange['110'],
            ['200']: colors.orange['120'],
            ['300']: colors.orange['130'],
            ['400']: colors.orange['140'],
            ['500']: colors.orange['150'],
            ['600']: colors.orange['160'],
        },
        unassessed: {
            ['50']: colors.pink['110'],
            ['100']: colors.pink['120'],
        },
    },
}
```

All colours here work, except `unassessed`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting one, but now I've worked it out I understand why it's happening.

The `unassessed` class is only used in one place currently, and it's computed at runtime, e.g.

```
<div [ngClass]="'border-' + stepState.colourClass + '-100'"
```

The variable `stepState.colourClass` is `unassessed`, this means Tailwind/Angular thinks it isn't being used and "tree shakes" it out of the final production build.

I ended up adding the class to the purge safelist, which fixes the issue. This is what the tailwind.config.js ended up looking like:

```
module.exports = {
purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.html', './src/**/*.ts'],
    safelist: [
        'border-unassessed-100',
        'bg-unassessed-50',
    ],
},
darkMode: false,
theme: {
    colors: {
        red: colors.red,
        blue: colors.blue,
        neutral: colors.grey,
        success: {
            ['50']: colors.green['100'],
            ['100']: colors.green['110'],
            ['200']: colors.green['120'],
            ['300']: colors.green['130'],
            ['400']: colors.green['140'],
            ['500']: colors.green['150'],
            ['600']: colors.green['160'],
        },
        warning: {
            ['50']: colors.orange['100'],
            ['100']: colors.orange['110'],
            ['200']: colors.orange['120'],
            ['300']: colors.orange['130'],
            ['400']: colors.orange['140'],
            ['500']: colors.orange['150'],
            ['600']: colors.orange['160'],
        },
        unassessed: {
            ['50']: colors.pink['110'],
            ['100']: colors.pink['120'],
        },
    },
}
```

}